# When is $b^2 - \{b-1\}_2$ with odd $b$ a perfect power of $2$? (The bracket-notation explained below)

Tags: number-theory, collatz-conjecture, exponential-diophantine-equations

For the complete extraction of the factor $p$ and its powers from a natural number $m$
let's define the notation $$ \{n\}_p := { n \over p^{\nu_p(n)}} $$
While looking at the question of existences of 2-step-cycles in the generalized Collatz-problem for $mx+1$ I arrived at the question for which odd $b$ the evaluation of $f(b)$
$$ f(b) = b^2 - \{b-1\}_2  \overset{?}=2^S \tag 1
$$
is a perfect power $ 2^S$.
I know, that $b=3$ and then $S=3$ is a solution (the famous $3^2-1=2^3$). Generating a list for sequential $b$ didn't suggest any useful pattern so far, so this didn't help me with a clue.

---

<sup>*I've put the same question also at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/374396/7710) having now some helpful answers, but still no full solution*</sup>

Comment: Your equation implies
$$(b-1)^2 < b^2 - \frac{b-1}{2} \leq 2^S < b^2.$$
Then $S$ must be odd (so that $2^S$ isn't a square) and $b = \lceil 2^{S/2} \rceil$.  So you can search for solutions by iterating through $S$ instead of $b$.  It seems unlikely (although not impossible) that any large solutions exist.

Comment: @RaviFernando - this is a nice observation. With another $S$, say $S_1$ I have a similar condition for admissible $m$ to allow a 2-(odd) step-cycle at all: $m=\lfloor 2^{S_1/2} \rfloor$ and $S_1$, $m$ odd ($m \in \{5,11,45,181,... \}$). I'll see what this incidence shall mean to me...